C# Attributes - How to instantiate a class through an attribute
I am trying to create a custom logging class in C#. My idea was to use attributes to set some extra metadata that the Logger class could use to create log entries.
So for example, I am trying to set a scope by doing something like
[Logging.Scope("MyFunc")]
void MyFunc(){
     //do stuff
     Logger.Log("Hello world!");
}

which should output: "MyFunc: Hello world!"
In the background I have implemented a static class called ScopeState which holds a string containing the currentScope
    public static class ScopeState
    {
        public static string CurrentScope { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    }

and a Scope class that derives the Attribute class
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class Scope : Attribute
    {
        public Scope(string currentScope)
        {
            ScopeState.CurrentScope = currentScope;
        }

    }

However, the Scope constructor is never called in my program.
    [Logging.Scope("Program.Main")]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger.Log("Hello, World!");
    }

What am I doing wrong?

Attributes on their own cannot do this. You’d also need to write a source generator.

Instead of tying to invent a custom logger class - why don't you use a pre-built one like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging ? You can set the scope by getting a logger from the logger factory and specifying the scope (name of the class) or just injecting using the ILogger via the constructor.
